# Create Designer Workflow which is associated to particular list in all the sites

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I want to create a designer workflow which is associated to particular list in all the sites. Which type of workflow I need to create? Site Workflow or Reusable workflow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to associate your workflow to a particular list then I believe you must choose `Reusable workflow`.

**Reusable List Workflows (Reusable Workflow)** : You can create a reusable list workflow (reusable workflow) in the top-level site in the site collection, and that workflow can be made globally reusable — meaning that the workflow can be associated to any `list`, `library`, or `content type` in the site collection. You can also create a reusable workflow in any subsite in the site collection; this workflow is available for reuse in that particular subsite.

If you want users to be able to use the workflows you are designing on `multiple sites`, `lists`, `libraries`, and `content types`, a reusable workflow will probably best meets your needs.

**Site workflows** : A site workflow is associated to a `site` — `not to a list, library, or content type`. So unlike most workflows, a site workflow is not running on a specific list item. Because of this, many of the actions that are available for items not available for site workflows.

In the browser, you start a site workflow or view the status of running site workflows by clicking the `Site Actions menu`, click `View All Site Content`, and then clicking `Site Workflows`.

If you want to create a workflow, but don’t need a list, library, or content type for the workflows, a site workflow will probably best meet your needs. For example, you can create a site workflow as a way for people to provide feedback about your site.

For more detailed information go through [Introduction to designing and customizing workflows](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Introduction-to-designing-and-customizing-workflows-32c9c0bf-5e20-4f74-8b9c-d3ea79f2962b)